# Is there any accessory available which can help me draw power from two different sources?

Tags: power-supply

I want to draw power from wall and also use my power bank as a backup power source, I want to flexibility to remove any of the power source without shutting it down.

I really dont want to chain the power bank as it will block the power bank forever, and I dont want a dedicated power bank there.

Comment: I think SE has a policy about buying recommendations that basically says "you're not supposed to ask" but I'm not certain and you should probably check...

Comment: I can put a UPS hat, that gives me the flexibility of switching power source anytime.